# VGA pixel grouping on STM32

Tags: graphics, arduino, stm32, pixel, vga

I have some code that displays a single pixel on screen through VGA but am a bit stuck on how I could set multiple pixels on screen where I want them. I set up two Timers for Vertical Sync and Horizontal Sync then using the V-Sync interrupt, I set a flag to allow PA8 to toggle and output a pixel at the correct timing based on the **SetCompare** value I set on the timer's channel. The STM32f103c8 is also overclocked to 128MHz. Here's the code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

//640x480 at 60Hz
static volatile int vflag = 0;

void setup() {

#define FLASH_ACR (*(volatile uint32_t*)(0x40022000))
FLASH_ACR = 0b110010; //enable flash prefetch and wait state to increase stability at higher freq

pinMode(PA0, PWM); //31,468.75Hz (Horizontal Sync) (Channel 1)
Timer2.pause();
Timer2.setOverflow(4067); //reload register value 
Timer2.setPrescaleFactor(1); //number that divides main clock 
Timer2.setCompare(1, 488); //12% duty cycle (Syncpulse/Wholeline) 
Timer2.setCompare(2, 2000); //0-4067 = vertical line going left or right respectively
Timer2.attachInterrupt(2, TRIGGER);
Timer2.refresh();
Timer2.resume();

pinMode(PA6, PWM); //60Hz (Vertical Sync) (Channel 1)
Timer3.pause();
Timer3.setOverflow(4183); //reload register value 
Timer3.setPrescaleFactor(510); //number that divides main clock 
Timer3.setCompare(1, 16); //0.38% duty cycle (Syncpulse/Wholeframe) 
Timer3.setCompare(2, 2000); //0-4183 = horizontal line going up or down respectively
Timer3.attachInterrupt(2, TRIGGER2); 
Timer3.refresh();
Timer3.resume();

pinMode(PA8, OUTPUT); //need to set PinMode in order for the ODR register to work

}

void loop() {

}

void TRIGGER(){
if(vflag==1){ 
__asm__ volatile (
"ldr r0, =(0x4001080C) \n\t" //GPIOA base address is 0x40010800 and ODR offset is 0x0C
"ldr r1, =(1<<8) \n\t" //turn on PA8
"ldr r2, =0 \n\t" //turn off PA8 

"str r1, [r0] \n\t" //turn on PA8
"str r2, [r0] \n\t" //turn off PA8

);
vflag = 0; //we set the vflag back to zero when were done outputing pixels.
}
}
```

I understand there's graphical defects/glitches and the code can be improved on but I'm trying to focus on how in theory this works. What I want to do is have a word display on screen, that word will be made up of letters, and those letters will be made up of groups of pixels. So then whats the best (or simplest) way to group pixels and execute them multiple times on-screen? Or how is this usually done?

Answer (score 1):

I do not code for **STM32** so even the code looks foreign to me however it sounds like you are hard-coding the individual pixels with timer... and generating VGA signal by some GPIO. That combination of methods is problematic to use for programmable graphics.

I am using **AVR32** (**UC3A** with much slower clock then yours) to doing VGA image using:

1. **screen buffer (videoram)**

simply I have entire screen image stored in MCU memory. So you can simply change it contents without changing the VGA output code ...

The problem is you need to have enough memory for the image (encoded in a way to enable direct transfer to VGA connector). I am using AVR32 with 16+32+32 KByte of RAM but most MCUs have much less RAM (static images can be stored in EPROM but then it would not be possible to change the image output). So in case you do not have enough either lower resolution to fit into memory or add external memory to your system.

2. **use integrated HW peripherial for VGA signal generation**

I have more versions of VGA signal generation working:

- SDRAM ... using SDRAM interface of the MCU
- SMC ... using SMC interface of the MCU
- SSC ... using synchronous serial interface

It all boils down to copying the screen buffer to IO interface at the [VGA dot clock (~30MHz)](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing). Then on HW side combining the used MCU pins into VGA signals

for speed you can use DMA.

On top of all this you need to generate the sync signals and that is all.

So look at your MCU datasheet and find interface capable of synchronous transfer at least 3 bit data (R,G,B) with VGA dot clock speed. The closer the clock is to VGA dot clock the better (as some VGA monitors  and LCDs do not tolerate too big difference)

the sync signals can be hardcoded or even encoded in the video ram.

The fastest is to use serial interface but the output is just B&W instead of RGB (unless you got 3 SSC units/channels) however you can send entire 8/16/32 pixels at once or by DMA directly so the MCU has time for other stuff and also requires much less VRAM.

My favourite is SDRAM interface (using just its data bus)

Here image from mine system:

[image: AVR32 VGA output]

Mine interconnection looks like this (using MCUs SDRAM interface version):

```
VGA <-  AT32UC3A0512
 R      PX10 (EBI_D0)
 G      PX09 (EBI_D1)
 B      PX08 (EBI_D2)
 Bright PX07 (EBI_D3)*
 HS     PA03
 VS     PA04
```

Here the relevant source:

**VGA_EBI_SDRAMC.h:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define _PA_VGA_HS  8
#define _PA_VGA_VS 16
#define _PAmo      24
volatile avr32_gpio_port_t *port_PA=&GPIO.port[AVR32_PIN_PA00>>5];
volatile U8 *SDRAM=(U8*)AVR32_EBI_CS0_ADDRESS;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- VGA 640x480x4 60Hz -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define VRAM_xs 304
#define VRAM_ys 400
#define VRAM_bs 4
#define VRAM_ls (VRAM_xs>>1)
U8      VRAM[VRAM_ls*VRAM_ys];
U8      VRAM_empty[VRAM_ls];
// Horizontal timing [us]
#define VGA_t0 3
#define VGA_t1 5
#define VGA_t2 32
// Vertikal timing [lines ~31.817us] aby voslo viac bodov tak je to natiahnute na 32us++
#define VGA_ys 525
#define VGA_VS 2
#define VGA_y0 (36+40)
#define VGA_y1 (VGA_y0+VRAM_ys)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void VGA_init();
void VGA_screen();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void VGA_init()
    {
    system_init();
    Disable_global_interrupt();
    gpio_configure_pins(port_PA,_PAmo,GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT|GPIO_INIT_HIGH);
    static const gpio_map_t EBI_GPIO_MAP[] =
        {
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_0_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_0_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_1_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_1_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_2_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_2_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_3_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_3_FUNCTION},
        };
    gpio_enable_module(EBI_GPIO_MAP, sizeof(EBI_GPIO_MAP) / sizeof(EBI_GPIO_MAP[0]));

    AVR32_SDRAMC.mr=0;  // normal mode
    AVR32_SDRAMC.tr=0;  // no refresh (T=0)
    AVR32_SDRAMC.cr=
         (AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NC_11_COLUMN_BITS <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NC_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NR_13_ROW_BITS    <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NR_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NB_TWO_BANKS      <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NB_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CAS_ONE_CYCLE        <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_CAS_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_DBW_16_BITS          <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_DBW_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TWR_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRC_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRP_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRCD_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRAS_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TXSR_OFFSET);
    AVR32_SDRAMC.hsr=AVR32_SDRAMC_HSR_DA_MASK;
    AVR32_SDRAMC.mdr=AVR32_SDRAMC_MDR_MD_SDRAM;

    // map SDRAM CS -> memory space
    AVR32_HMATRIX.sfr[AVR32_EBI_HMATRIX_NR]|=1<<AVR32_EBI_SDRAM_CS;
    AVR32_HMATRIX.sfr[AVR32_EBI_HMATRIX_NR];

    U32 a;
    for (a=0;a<VRAM_ls*VRAM_ys;a++) VRAM[a]=0;
    for (a=0;a<VRAM_ls;a++) VRAM_empty[a]=0;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void VGA_screen()
    {
    U32 a,x,y,c,PA,t0;
    wait_start(t0);
    for (;;)
        {
        for (PA=_PAmo,a=0,y=0;y<VGA_ys;y++)
            {
            wait_start(t0);
            if (y==     0) PA^=_PA_VGA_VS; else PA^=0;  // VS on
            if (y==VGA_VS) PA^=_PA_VGA_VS; else PA^=0;  // VS off
            PA^=_PA_VGA_HS;                             // HS on
            port_PA->ovrc=PA^_PAmo;
            port_PA->ovrs=PA;
            wait_us(t0,VGA_t0);
            PA^=_PA_VGA_HS;                             // HS off
            port_PA->ovrc=PA^_PAmo;
            port_PA->ovrs=PA;
            wait_us(t0,VGA_t1);
            *SDRAM=0; // blank (black)
            if ((y>=VGA_y0)&&(y<VGA_y1))
             for (x=0;x<VRAM_ls;x++)
                 {
                 c=VRAM[a];
                 *SDRAM=c>>4; // write pixel into SDRAM interface (address is ignored as I use only data bus pins)
                 a++;
                 *SDRAM=c; // write pixel into SDRAM interface (address is ignored as I use only data bus pins)

                 }
            *SDRAM=0; // blank (black)
            wait_us(t0,VGA_t2);
            }
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Main.cpp:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "System\include.h"
#include "pic_zilog_inside.h"
//#include "VGA_EBI_SMC.h"
#include "VGA_EBI_SDRAMC.h"
//#include "VGA_SSC.h"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void pic_copy(U8 *dst,U32 dst_xs,U32 dst_ys,U32 dst_bs,U8 *src,U32 src_xs,U32 src_ys,U32 src_bs)
    {
    U32 x0,y0,a0,l0;
    U32 x1,y1,a1,l1;
    U32 a; U8 c,m;
    l0=1; l1=1;
    if (dst_bs==1) l0=dst_xs>>3;
    if (dst_bs==2) l0=dst_xs>>2;
    if (dst_bs==4) l0=dst_xs>>1;
    if (dst_bs==8) l0=dst_xs;
    if (src_bs==1) l1=src_xs>>3;
    if (src_bs==2) l1=src_xs>>2;
    if (src_bs==4) l1=src_xs>>1;
    if (src_bs==8) l1=src_xs;

    for (a0=0;a0<dst_ys*l0;a0++) dst[a0]=0;

    for (y0=0;y0<dst_ys;y0++)
        {
        y1=(y0*(src_ys-1))/(dst_ys-1);
        a0=l0*y0;
        a1=l1*y1;
        for (x0=0;x0<dst_xs;x0++)
            {
            x1=(x0*(src_xs-1))/(dst_xs-1);
            c=0;
            if (src_bs==1)
                {
                c=src[a1+(x1>>3)];
                c>>=7-(x1&7);
                c&=1;
                }
            if (src_bs==4)
                {
                c=src[a1+(x1>>1)];
                if (U32(x0&1)==0) c>>=4;
                c&=15;
                }
            if (dst_bs==1)
                {
                c<<=7-(x0&7);
                a=a0+(x0>>3);
                dst[a]|=c; if (!c) dst[a]^=c;
                }
            if (dst_bs==4)
                {
                if (c) c=15;
                if (U32(x0&1)==0) { c<<=4; m=0x0F; } else m=0xF0;
                a=a0+(x0>>1);
                dst[a]&=m;
                dst[a]|=c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
    {
    VGA_init();
    pic_copy
        (
        (U8*)VRAM,
        VRAM_xs,
        VRAM_ys,
        VRAM_bs,
        (U8*)pic_zilog_inside,
        pic_zilog_inside_xs,
        pic_zilog_inside_ys,
        pic_zilog_inside_bs
        );
    VGA_screen();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**pic_zilog_inside.h:**

```cpp
const U32 pic_zilog_inside_xs=640;
const U32 pic_zilog_inside_ys=480;
const U32 pic_zilog_inside_bs=1;
const U32 pic_zilog_inside[]= // hard coded image
    {
    0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0x80000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,
    0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000001,0x80000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,
...
    0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000001,0x80000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,
    0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000001,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,
    };
```

The function `pic_copy` just copies hard-coded image into VRAM.

The function `VGA_screen()` creates the VGA signal in endless loop so other tasks must be encoded into ISRs or hard coded into pause code or between individual frames (however this is really demanding on mine setup as I got small MCU clock so there is not much room for other stuff to do). The VRAM is encoded in 16 colors (4 bits per pixel)

```
         8 4 2 1
Brightness B G R
```

The brightness should just adds some voltage to R,G,B with few resistors and diodes  but newer implemented it on HW side instead I have this circuit (8 colors only):

[image: VGA]

The diodes must be fast with the same barrier voltage and capacitors are 1nF. Its to avoid glitching of the image due to used interface data bus timing. Also the diodes are needed for the brightness if added in future for more info see the R2R current problem in here:

- [Generating square wave in AVR Assembly without PWM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008329/2521214)

**[Edit1] I made huge changes in code:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- VGA EBI SDRAMC DMACA ver: 3.0 --------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
 VGA <- AT32UC3A3256
 R      PX10 (EBI_D0)
 G      PX09 (EBI_D1)
 B      PX08 (EBI_D2)
 Bright PX07 (EBI_D3)*
 /HS    PX58
 /VS    PX59

Button  PB10 (Bootloader)
debug   PX54 (timing of TC00)

*/
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//#define _Debug  AVR32_PIN_PX54
#define _Button AVR32_PIN_PB10
#define _VGA_HS (1<<(AVR32_PIN_PX58&31))
#define _VGA_VS (1<<(AVR32_PIN_PX59&31))
#define _VGA_mask (_VGA_HS|_VGA_VS)
volatile avr32_gpio_port_t *port_VGA=&GPIO.port[AVR32_PIN_PX58>>5];
volatile U8 *SDRAM=(U8*)AVR32_EBI_CS0_ADDRESS;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- VGA 640x480x4 60Hz -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define VRAM_xs 256
#define VRAM_ys 192
#define VRAM_bs 8
#define VRAM_ls ((VRAM_xs*VRAM_bs)>>3)
volatile static U8 VRAM[VRAM_ls*VRAM_ys];
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     |------------------------|
     |         V sync         |
     | |----------------------|
     | |       V back         |
     | | |------------------| |
     |H|H|                  |H|
     |s|b|  Video 640x480   |f|
     |y|a|    525 lines     |r|
     |n|c|      60 Hz       |o|
     |c|k|                  |n|
     | | |------------------|t|
     | |       V front        |
     |------------------------|

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// VGA 640x480 60Hz H timing [pixels] dot clock = 25.175MHz
#define VGA_H_front 16
#define VGA_H_sync  96
#define VGA_H_back  48
#define VGA_H_video 640
// VGA 640x480 60Hz H timing [us] Ht = H/25.175, Hf = Vf*(VGA_V_video+VGA_V_front+VGA_V_sync+VGA_V_back)
#define VGA_Ht_front 1
#define VGA_Ht_sync  2
#define VGA_Ht_back  1
#define VGA_Hf 31500
// VGA 640x480 60Hz V timing [lines]
#define VGA_V_video 480
#define VGA_V_front 10
#define VGA_V_sync  2
#define VGA_V_back  33
#define VGA_Vf 60
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void VGA_init();
void VGA_screen();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__attribute__((__interrupt__)) static void ISR_TC00_VGA()   // TC0 chn:0 VGA horizontal frequency
    {                                                       // 8us every 31.75us -> 25% of CPU power
    tc_read_sr(&AVR32_TC0,0);                               // more centered image requires +1 us to VGA_Ht_back -> 28% CPU power

    #define y0 (VGA_V_video)
    #define y1 (y0+VGA_V_front)
    #define y2 (y1+VGA_V_sync)
    #define y3 (y2+VGA_V_back)
    #define yscr0 ((VGA_V_video>>1)-VRAM_ys)
    #define yscr1 (yscr0+(VRAM_ys<<1))
    static volatile U8 *p;
    static volatile U32 y=y3;

    #ifdef _Debug
    gpio_set_gpio_pin(_Debug);
    #endif

    // init state
    if (y>=y3){ y=0; p=VRAM; port_VGA->ovrs=_VGA_mask; }
    // VS sync
    if (y==y1) port_VGA->ovrc=_VGA_VS;      // VS = L
    if (y==y2) port_VGA->ovrs=_VGA_VS;      // VS = H
    // HS sync
    wait_us(VGA_Ht_front);                  // front
    port_VGA->ovrc=_VGA_HS;                 // HS = L
    wait_us(VGA_Ht_sync);                   // sync
    port_VGA->ovrs=_VGA_HS;                 // HS = H
    wait_us(VGA_Ht_back);                   // back

    // 8bit pixelformat DMACA, scan doubler + y offset
    if ((y>=yscr0)&&(y<yscr1))
        {
        // Enable the DMACA
        AVR32_DMACA.dmacfgreg = (1 << AVR32_DMACA_DMACFGREG_DMA_EN_OFFSET);

        // Src Address: the source_data address
        AVR32_DMACA.sar2 = (uint32_t)p;
        // Dst Address: the dest_data address
        AVR32_DMACA.dar2 = (uint32_t)SDRAM;
        // Linked list ptrs: not used.
        AVR32_DMACA.llp2 = 0x00000000;
        // Channel 2 Ctrl register low
        AVR32_DMACA.ctl2l =
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_INT_EN_OFFSET)       |  // Enable interrupts
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_DST_TR_WIDTH_OFFSET) |  // Dst transfer width: 8bit (1,2 znasobi dotclock na 2x)
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_SRC_TR_WIDTH_OFFSET) |  // Src transfer width: 8bit
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_DINC_OFFSET)         |  // Dst address increment: increment
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_SINC_OFFSET)         |  // Src address increment: increment
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_DST_MSIZE_OFFSET)    |  // Dst burst transaction len: 1 data items (each of size DST_TR_WIDTH)
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_SRC_MSIZE_OFFSET)    |  // Src burst transaction len: 1 data items (each of size DST_TR_WIDTH)
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_TT_FC_OFFSET)        |  // transfer type:M2M, flow controller: DMACA
            (1 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_DMS_OFFSET)          |  // Destination master: HSB master 2
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_SMS_OFFSET)          |  // Source master: HSB master 1
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_LLP_D_EN_OFFSET)     |  // Not used
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2L_LLP_S_EN_OFFSET);       // Not used

        // Channel 2 Ctrl register high
        AVR32_DMACA.ctl2h =
            ((VRAM_ls) << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2H_BLOCK_TS_OFFSET) | // Block transfer size
            (0           << AVR32_DMACA_CTL2H_DONE_OFFSET);      // Not done

        // Channel 2 Config register low
        AVR32_DMACA.cfg2l =
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CFG2L_HS_SEL_DST_OFFSET) | // Destination handshaking: ignored because the dst is memory
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CFG2L_HS_SEL_SRC_OFFSET);  // Source handshaking: ignored because the src is memory.

        // Channel 2 Config register high
        AVR32_DMACA.cfg2h =
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CFG2H_DEST_PER_OFFSET) | // Dest hw handshaking itf: ignored because the dst is memory.
            (0 << AVR32_DMACA_CFG2H_SRC_PER_OFFSET);   // Source hw handshaking itf: ignored because the src is memory.

        // Enable Channel 2 : start the process.
        AVR32_DMACA.chenreg = ((4 << AVR32_DMACA_CHENREG_CH_EN_OFFSET) | (4 << AVR32_DMACA_CHENREG_CH_EN_WE_OFFSET));

        // DMACA is messing up first BYTE so send it by SW before DMA
        *SDRAM=*p;

        // scan doubler increment only every second scanline
        if ((y&1)==1) p+=VRAM_ls;
        }
    *SDRAM=0; y++;

    #ifdef _Debug
    gpio_clr_gpio_pin(_Debug);
    #endif

    #undef y0
    #undef y1
    #undef y2
    #undef y3
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void VGA_init()
    {
    system_init();
    Disable_global_interrupt();
    gpio_configure_pin(_Button,GPIO_DIR_INPUT);
    #ifdef _Debug
    gpio_configure_pin(_Debug,GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT);
    #endif
    gpio_configure_pins(port_VGA,_VGA_mask,GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT|GPIO_INIT_HIGH);
    static const gpio_map_t EBI_GPIO_MAP[] =
        {
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_0_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_0_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_1_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_1_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_2_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_2_FUNCTION},
        { AVR32_EBI_DATA_3_PIN, AVR32_EBI_DATA_3_FUNCTION},
        };
    gpio_enable_module(EBI_GPIO_MAP, sizeof(EBI_GPIO_MAP) / sizeof(EBI_GPIO_MAP[0]));

    AVR32_SDRAMC.mr=0;  // normal mode
    AVR32_SDRAMC.tr=0;  // no refresh (T=0)
    AVR32_SDRAMC.cr=
         (AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NC_11_COLUMN_BITS <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NC_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NR_13_ROW_BITS    <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NR_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NB_TWO_BANKS      <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_NB_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_CAS_ONE_CYCLE        <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_CAS_OFFSET)
        |(AVR32_SDRAMC_DBW_16_BITS          <<AVR32_SDRAMC_CR_DBW_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TWR_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRC_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRP_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRCD_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TRAS_OFFSET)
        |(0                                 <<AVR32_SDRAMC_TXSR_OFFSET);
    AVR32_SDRAMC.hsr=AVR32_SDRAMC_HSR_DA_MASK;
    AVR32_SDRAMC.mdr=AVR32_SDRAMC_MDR_MD_SDRAM;

    // map SDRAM CS -> memory space
    AVR32_HMATRIX.sfr[AVR32_EBI_HMATRIX_NR]|=1<<AVR32_EBI_SDRAM_CS;
    AVR32_HMATRIX.sfr[AVR32_EBI_HMATRIX_NR];

    for (U32 a=0;a<VRAM_ls*VRAM_ys;a++) VRAM[a]=0;

    timer_init(&AVR32_TC0,0,VGA_Hf,ISR_TC00_VGA,0);
    Enable_global_interrupt();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now its enough to call `VGA_init();` and the stuff runs in background using Timer and DMA between internal RAM and EBI SDRAM interface. It uses only 25% of CPU power in current configuration. However half of VRAM is wasted as only 4 bits are used so high nibel might be used for back buffering to compensate. I also downclock the stuf to 66MHz as I do not have enough RAM for higher resolutions.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, I do want to summarize in order to make sure I'm understanding how this is done. To output pixels you first put them in an array, and then copy them into ram where the hardware peripheral can access them. Then (from looking at your for-loop), you put the pixels one by one into the SDRAM address, incrementing each time. For now, I don't care for color and want the simplest implementation possible, so black and white is fine. You say it all boils down to getting that pixel data out into the hardware interface AT the speed of the pixel clock.

Comment: So since I already setup the H-sync and V-sync signals with Timers, would setting up a third timer (running at the pixel clock i.e. 25.175MHz in my case) and firing interrupts every 0.0397 Microseconds (1/25,175,000) to set every pixel be correct? or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: @SirSpunk just by writing into SDRAM interface the MCU will output both data and address buss (with high speed... only data bus is used). If you do some timer counter instead you can but the output result must be masked by your VRAM/image whatever otherwise you would just output dots or fully filled screen. For simplest impementation you can use B&W where serial interfaces are your best option but you need such that have no start/stop/parity bits nor gaps some USARTS are configurable enough to do that but some MCUs have also synchronous serial ports (SSC) those are perfect for this.

Comment: @SirSpunk PS the SDRAM address is not incremented (as address is not used there is no need to changing it) so I simply copy the whole videoram pixel by pixel into the same SDRAM address... I doubt you can have stable 25.175 MHz  timer take in mind you need some instructions just to handle ISR so there is not much room for accessing VRAM and masking output. Most likely you would have jitter (causing some pixels will be wider)  or the system would completely freeze (as there is no room for CPU other than ISR but I could be wrong as I do nto have experience with your platform

Comment: @SirSpunk I added new version of code (was palying with DMA), right now its 256x192x8bpp VRAM (uses only lover 4 bits) 60Hz running in background using only 25% of CPU. Its possible to lower the CPU usage even more by using linked lists DMA instead of delays however I am too lazy to do it for now ... How is your VGA going did you made it ?

Comment: I managed to lower CPU consumption to 8.4% by removing all waits/delays (exploiting AVR32 Timer/counter comparators triggering ISR multiple times per period as my original ideas using linked lists did not work due to HW bugs in DMACA modules). I ended up by having HSync as timer PWM, and the DMA transfer is triggered also on Timer. However as the stuff is exploiting some HW buggy timings I will not post the code not to confuse others ...