# STM32 - Capable of generating VGA signal?

Tags: stm32, mbed, vga

To be clear, I'm very new to STM32 and MBED programming, but is it possible to create valid VGA signal, using STM32 nucleo-F070RB board? I've picked up [this standard](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/800x600@60Hz), and my goal is to display "something" on screen. With this i mean I should have control which pixel i want to, well, turn on.

For demo, here is my (very crude) sketch:

```
#include <mbed.h>

DigitalOut led(LED1);
DigitalOut h_sync(PC_3);
DigitalOut v_sync(PC_2);
DigitalOut c_red(PC_0);

int main() {
        h_sync = 1;
        v_sync = 1;
        int line_count = 0;
        int color_red = 0;
    while(1) {
        wait_us(21);
        h_sync = 0;
        wait_us(3);
        h_sync = 1;
        wait_ns(2);
        line_count++;
        color_red++;
        if (color_red == 16) { color_red = 0; c_red = !c_red; }
        if (line_count == 601) v_sync = 0;
        if (line_count == 605) v_sync = 1;
        if (line_count == 628) { line_count = 0; c_red = 0; color_red = 0; }
    }
}
```

I have connected V-Sync to V-Sync of my monitor, same with H-Sync and c_red (color red) through 560Ohm resistor to RED signal. And it (kind of) worked! It displayed red strips every 16 lines. Perfect, but I need to be able to control every pixel (if it's possible). I've seen some VGA libraries (maybe), but i really need to write it myself - something very crude. I just only want to have some sort of control over pixels, not the some super-super something (Just for me to learn :) ). And because I don't have much experience with STMs, after hours i was not able to "convince" my board to generate such "high-speed" signals, so, it is after all possible?

I was using MBED's Ticker function to generate the timing for each pixel, but it did not work - the fastest the Ticker went for me was something around few miliseconds, far too much. Can I use timer interrupts? Or something else?

Comment: delay will  not work for sure

Comment: Have seen it happen. I think it was an STM32F4. But your question is quite off topic for so though.

Comment: Read the VGA spec with regard to timing.  It's quite demanding of correct timing.  I'm fairly certain your delay of 2 nanoseconds??? is not accurate.

Comment: @TomServo yep, 2 nanos are for the back porch section (I couldn't do 2,2), but yes, I know this is wrong (even tho my monitor recognized it correctly), It was my first test, but HOW should I do it better? timer interrupts? Tickers? something else? Thanks.

Comment: I had tried a similar project once but got involved in other things.  I found [this site](https://www.artekit.eu/vga-output-using-a-36-pin-stm32/) very intriguing.  Perhaps it will help you too.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893678/2521214 its VGA generation on AVR32 66MHz using single timer and DMA + EBI (SDRAM) intergace. STM32 is slightly worse than AVR32 UC3 however should be still doable you just need fast enough interface (GPIO will most likely not work fast enough). At worst you can use SPI 30MHz for 640x480 B&W... Monitors are picky on HS,VS frequencies so create them by timer ...