# Problem with setting pixels to OLED display 128x64

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

So I had a class "SnakeGame" that handle my game.
I have another class named engine which is just a class the take the player input and setting pixels (a header file and main file):

```
void Engine::SetPixels(int positionX, int positionY, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    display.fillRect(positionX, positionY, sizeX, sizeY, WHITE);
    Serial.println("drawing");
    display.display();
}

void Engine::Display() {
    display.display();
    Serial.println("Display");
}
```

In my .ino file and in the `loop()` function (I am currently using Visual micro):

```
SnakeGame game;

void loop() {
    // Calculate delta time
    unsigned long frameStartTime = millis();
    unsigned long deltaTimeMillis = frameStartTime - timeOld;
    float deltaTime = deltaTimeMillis / 1000.0;
    timeOld = frameStartTime;

    // Update
    engine.updateLoop(deltaTime);
    engine.SetPixels(x, y, 16, 16);
    x, y++;

    game.updateLoop(engine);
}
```

The code was running fine and the `serial.println` still printing but there are nothing on my display which was weird. Of course, I remembered to call `display.begin()` in the `setup()`. If i just remove the `SnakeGame game` line it would be working at normal. Even if i didn't call or do anything with that variable but if it was there it would still:

1. Constantly restart the arduino
2. Didn't draw any pixels to the display.

Why is that? Here is my full [script](https://gist.github.com/longtran2904/2f46330be5a796a5b7298eef12506cc9)

Comment: what happens when you rem out the `Serial.println("Starting");`

Comment: It just printed out at normal

Comment: so if the `println` is corrupting your LCD code then there is some block ... either they use the same line or whatever resource ...

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the println but the pointer. Because if i call the function directly and remove the pointer it would work fine.

Comment: Well your code does not contain `engine` so its hard to tell what could be wrong...  However not sure what compiler you use on MCUs there is usually GCC and that one is not very good for OOP it has many bugs especially with constructors/destructors. So it might be confused by that your struct is more class then struct... And ARDUINO framework has its  own quirks and bugs too

Comment: what is MCUs and GCC? Can you send me the docs plz! And i think the problem is come from the constructor

Comment: Ohhh boy ...  **MCU** is Micro Controller Unit  (similar to CPU but contain whole computer inside with memory, perpherials etc. on single chip) ... Arduino is just framework/library not HW ... You most likely run on some old 8bit Atmell MCU like ATMEGA ... [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) is freeware compiler (PC Program that converts you text files with source code into binary that you burn onto the MCU by USB,SPI,RS232 or whatever ISP system). If you want datasheet to your MCU you need first know which one you have (its written on top of the chip)

Comment: Older GCC versions for MCU had some serious flaws like they some times (or all the time) did not run class constructors automatically so you had to call them on your own for each class instance just to be sure ... Also if you got many `#ifndef / #ifdef` macros they tend to compile wrongly on ocasions ... and that is just the tip of the iceberg... Newer GCC compilers are slightly better but so mutch slower and often with newer IDE editors with annoying functions like auto formatting (implying its own formatting on you) which cant be disabled making them absolutely unusable for serious work.

Comment: i am using arduino uno r3 which has a ATmega328P. The IDE is visual studio 2019 and visual micro plugin.

Comment: "your struct is more class then struct". I thought class and struct in c++ is the same. Except class default is private and struct is public

Comment: @Spektre Here is all my script https://gist.github.com/longtran2904/2f46330be5a796a5b7298eef12506cc9. Idk what the problem is but it was really annoying. When you look at my .ino file  you can see that i had a ```SnakeGame game``` variable. If i remove that line anything work fine. I don't even need to call any function from it. Just the existion of that line of code will make my program:

1. Constanly restart
2. Cant draw to the display even though the println was still printing out.

Comment: that line will call the constructor of the SnakeGame and in there The only thing I can see it could do something wrong is `Serial.println("PLEASE WORK");` that one I assume sends message to some interface like RS232 but if the interface used is not yet configured it might do anything like freeze the system for good ... try to rem it out if it makes any difference

Comment: I've removed that and it still wouldn't fix the problem

Comment: @Spektre This is so wierd. If i had that line of declare variable code the code still run and call the engine.SetPixels() function but there was nothing that drew to the display. Why? I tried to place some break point to see and it actually run througth the code without any errors. And the constructor is just assign some value to some variables so it shouldn't cause any bugs. If i commented the constructor it would still not been fixed. Maybe there something about the #include statement where i include more than one libraries?

Comment: there might be a tons of things going on wrong ....  You need to build&check your code gradually. What you done was glueing too many things together at once. If you add the stuff gradually you would know directly what part of code breaks the functionality.

Comment: The obvious stuff to check is the display: 1. is it responding on its address (probe the I2C)? mines are at 0x3C  but yours might be different.  2. what speed you use for I2C? those displays are susceptible to jitter and also have problems in low speeds. I am using ~150/2 KHz  for SW I2C (as HW does not work for the display) on my 50MHz AVR32 but you have most likely much worse MCU so try lower speed like 40KHz or less. 3. add freeze indicator to your code  (like blinking LED in your main code  loop not ISR!!!) as if you have many ISR they can overwhelm the MCU not executing main loop at all

Comment: 1. I used spi and i didn't need to pass in the address for the function.
2. I am using SW spi and an arduino uno r3 (what is its MCU?), how to check the speed of it?

Comment: Do you had the adafruit oled display like me? Can you run my code on arduino and see what wrong with it?

Comment: I do not use Adafruit I have my own libs... I also do not use Arduino to be clear I hate it as the old C/C++ in AVR studio is way better and Arduino framework hides the HW architecture making impossible to use it properly and fast. If you want to know which MCU you use just look at the chip its written on it...  from a quick look at Google images it uses [ATMEGA 328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) which is old 8bit MCU IIRC its only 16 MIPS.

Comment: So if you use SPI for display is it configured correctly? what interface your `Serial.println` using? as you are on arduino they both  might be done in SW (another arduino related downside) so if sharing the same interrupts they might be conflicting eachother

Comment: @Spektre i finally know what wrong with my code. In the ```SnakeGame.h``` i declared 2 arrays of char whose size are about 512MB each so the total was 1024MB. The arduino's ram is just about 2KB so it was half of it. Therefore it would just crash when run the code because it tried to access more memory than it had. I was really new to c++ and arduino so i didn't have any experience with memory management before.

Comment: @Spektre I was tried to make a snake game and needed the arrays to store all the snake's body positions. Do you have any suggestion to optimize this? My current solution is just make the snake smaller to decrease the length of the array by making a pixel bigger (divided it to chunks). Should i use vector and increase the size of its over time?

Comment: 1. how long your snake would be? 2. you can encode the snake with lines instead fo pixels that would lower the memory requirements a lot. the iteration of movement will be just resizing first and last line size ... so I think 256 turns is more than enough for your snake ... angle and size for each lines so 512Bytes ...

Comment: Also you can use the displays frame buffer (1KByte) directly and just remember first and last pixel of snake ... while iterating you just scan for the next pixel in 4 pixel  neibrhood  however you need to make sure your snake lines will not touch!!! that would require just `x0,y0,x1,y1` so 4 bytes instead of your 1024 MBytes :)

Comment: btw here [ATmega 328p datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)  yes it has  just 2KBytes of SRAM. LCD driver uses 1KByte + some variables, so you have slightly less than  1KByte left and beware the C++ engine requires some memory too (you know heap, stack, variables, etc...) so if you have const tables and stuff do not forget to set it static for example `static const char text[]="bla bla bla..."` that usually moves the stuff to EEPROM. Some compilers have switches for this so check documentations

Comment: I would avoid any dynamic allocations on MCU... btw I am mostly coding on AT32UC3 MCU familly and there you got 16+32+32 KByte of SRAM so I rarely have problem with not enough memory However for some projects (both commercial and hobby) I hit the limits time to time. For example see this QA: [VGA signal generated by MCU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893678/2521214) the image takes a lot of MCU memory. btw you should create an answer and accept it I think it would be useful for others ... Its not something people think of while checking code

Comment: btw if you want to try the VGA on your arduino you can forget it ... The best I could do on ATMega168p was to drive B&W LCD flat panel I wanted to use as oscilloscope but the speed was not enough to do anything else but display texts. That was ages ago before I was forced to use UC3 due to work... and which I do not regret

Comment: @Spektre
1. My snake maximum length would be 512 units (for now).
2. Can you explain more about your lines solution? Because idk how many times the snake will turn so how do i store the angles and stuff...?

Comment: I think that is worth for a separate question... you got 0/90/180/270 deg angles only that is 2 bits. Each line can be up to max size of LCD in length so `0...127 -> 7` bits you can also limit the size to 6 bits (`0..63`) and encode longer lines as 2 that would fit into single BYTE... If you ask new question comment me here so I would be notified ... in such case I would answer in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code is I had 2 arrays of char whose size was about 512MB each so the total was 1024MB. I used so much more rams than the Arduino have so it would freeze and stop working.